# Handlebars template in Marionette application with edit functionality

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, handlebars.js, marionette

In my marionette application I have one view which holds handlebar template within {{#each}} expression to display collection of information. Now I want to add "Edit functionality to information displayed using this template. I am thinking of defining one more editable template. But I need help on How should I;
1) render editable template on click of some button
2) send displayed data to editable template as source
3) after changes save request complete how to restore display template with updated values without refreshing complete parent view.

Can any one guide me to implement this functionality; or else can suggest me other better alternative approach to do this.

Comment: This might help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23628745/is-there-onblur-nanlog-in-marionette/23630023#23630023

Comment: @WilbertvandeRidder Thanks Wilbert for your reply; this link have given me some direction. I want to further clear some of my doubts. Firstly about defining region for editable template; as I said in problem statement my display template is going to render multiple time within {{#each}} for collection from my parent model. So How can define region identical for each other. secondly how can I pass the required model instance from the same collection to editable view lets say from your loadEditMode(). Thanks again.

Comment: @WilbertvandeRidder One more doubt I am using multiple handlebar templates to display single entity using handlebar's {{>}} expression; which don't have marionette view definition. This will create problem for me to restore the display template on save click. So It will be very helpful if you elaborate me on this points. Thanks

Comment: Can you create a jsfiddle showing the essential points of what you have now? You can fork the example in the other question such that backbone and marionette are already available.

Comment: @WilbertvandeRidder Thanks Wilbert; your link helped me to get my half of the work done.

Comment: no problem! If you need more help, just elaborate on what you have already and we can see from there.